# error: static data member 'gtest_registering_dummy_' not allowed in local class 'RadioHidlTest_v1_5_startNetworkScan_InvalidArgument_Test'

Tags: android, android-vts

I want  to make VtsHalRadioV1_5TargetTest  of vts , when I cd hardware/interfaces/radio/1.5/vts/functional and execute the mm command to compile the current module，the results show as below

error: static data member 'gtest_registering_dummy_' not allowed in local class 'RadioHidlTest_v1_5_startNetworkScan_InvalidArgument_Test'

I want to compile this module and get VtsHalRadioV1_5TargetTest

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXSBm.png)